# SQL Server to S3 via Sqoop

Tags: sql-server, sqoop, avro

I've seen some conflicting information on whether or not Sqoop is able to handle the following use case: I'm pretty sure I've seen it done in the past, but want to double-check.. Here's the bash script:

```
sqoop-import -Dmapreduce.job.user.classpath.first=true --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://stuff:1433;database=prd_swift_core;user=username;password=red123:" --table MYTABLE -m 1 --as-avrodatafile --target-dir s3n://bucket/folder1/folder2/MYTABLE/DATE
```

It finishes but the table is never shown in S3. Table is roughly 20gigs, not sure if this is a limitation?

Answer (score 0):

It will work.

For people trying to do this, you need to add the --fetch-size parameter otherwise it will try to import the entire table at once.  23 gigs successfully moved from SqlServer to S3.